# Breadcrumb bar doesn't show link to navigate previous folder level on hover winui3

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, breadcrumbs, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I added breadcrumb component in my project and tried several things, but link on hover on breadcrumb is not shown to navigate back to previously displayed folders.

My code for breadcrumb is here

```xml
<BreadcrumbBar
    x:Name="FolderBreadcrumbBar"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Breadcrumbs}" 
    ItemClicked="FolderBreadcrumbBar_ItemClicked"> 
    <BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Breadcrumb">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Label}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
</BreadcrumbBar>
```

I was trying to have hyperlink enabled to navigate to previous folder level in breadcrumb, Like below example

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctDCb.png)

On click on Folder1 it navigates back to that level, but my issue is the hyperlink on Folder1 is not shown to trigger my onclick handler.

It doesn't highlight the link on hover of the mouse like below ex:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iySLz.png)

Can someone please help where I'm going wrong or how I can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `my issue is the hyperlink on Folder1 is not shown to trigger my onclick handler.` There is no hyperlink in the BreadcrumbBar from the code you post. Could you please be more specific about what you want to get? The image you shared is just a normal look of the `BreadcrumbBar`.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, for the breadcrumb bar can you please provide me a working example with onClick handler on breadcrumb. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using the sample code from this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/breadcrumbbar. I think this should be the same code that you are using. I can click on the items of the `BreadcrumbBar` and it will trigger the `FolderBreadcrumbBar_ItemClicked`. I'm testing on windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HyperlinkButton`.

**.xaml**

```xml
<BreadcrumbBar
    x:Name="FolderBreadcrumbBar"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Breadcrumbs}">
    <BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Breadcrumb">
            <HyperlinkButton
                Content="{x:Bind Label}"
                Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
</BreadcrumbBar>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is HyperlinkButton hyperlinkButton &&
        hyperlinkButton.DataContext is Breadcrumb breadcrumb)
    {
    }
}
```

**ANOTHER OPTION**

As requested, if you need to use the `ItemClicked` from `BreadcrumbBar`, you can do it this way. The highlight will be low-contrast though.

```xml
<BreadcrumbBar
    x:Name="FolderBreadcrumbBar"
    ItemClicked="FolderBreadcrumbBar_ItemClicked"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Breadcrumbs}">
    <BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Breadcrumb">
            <BreadcrumbBarItem Content="{Binding}">
                <BreadcrumbBarItem.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Breadcrumb">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Label}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BreadcrumbBarItem.ContentTemplate>
            </BreadcrumbBarItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
</BreadcrumbBar>
```

Comment: Andrew, can you also help me by showing the click event on the breadcrumb, the one event handler on the breadcrumb ItemClicked it's not working for me. Do I need to add click event on HyperlinkButton? 

can you please give me an working example with both xaml and xaml.cs changes?

Comment: Sorry. You are right. The ``BreadcrumBar``'s click won't work. You need to use ``HyperlinkButton``'s click. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Andrew this works! 
But would have been better if ItemClicked breadcrumb event handler would work. I was trying to do something similar.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/breadcrumbbar

Comment: For anyone else that might stumble upon this, you have to handle the navigation yourself. So if Folder 1 is clicked, you need to write the code to navigate to Folder 1. That navigation is not wired up for you.